# Helpme in for-loop in format (String,Int)

Tags: swift, for-loop

I am confused about a for-loop in Swift that I found in The Swift Programming Language (Swift 5.7). The code is as follows:

```swift
let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    "Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25],
]
var largest = 0
for (_, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    for number in numbers {
        if number > largest {
            largest = number
        }
    }
}
print(largest)
```

I'm specifically confused about the line 7, where the for-loop is used in the pattern `"for (String, Int) in sth"`. When I replace `_` with another text, that text never appears in the response. Can anyone tell me how to use this for-loop and what the difference is between this type of for-loop and other types?

Comment: You have a Dictionary. Your `for ... in` loop is traversing the key/value pairs in that dictionary. When you use `for ... in` on a Dictionary, you get tuples of `(Key, Value)` as Rob says. If you enter the code `print(type(of: interestingNumbers))` you get a result of `Dictionary<String, Array<Int>>`. That tells you you have a Dictionary with a Key of type String, and a value of type `Array<Int>`.

Comment: Note that Dictionaries are "unordered collections" meaning that they do not have any inherent ordering to their key/value pairs. A for loop that loops through the key/value pairs in your dictionary will loop through them in an order that will probably be different than the order in which defined them in your dictionary.

Comment: When I ran `for (key, value) in interestingNumbers` code on your `interestingNumbers` Dictionary, I got the Squares first, then the Fibonacci numbers, then the prime numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a Dictionary is treated as a Sequence, as in this case, its Element is `(Key, Value)`. So the `_` here is saying that the algorithm does not require the key. Only the value is bound, as `numbers` (an array of integers).

An equivalent way of writing this loop would be:

```
for numbers in interestingNumbers.values { ... }
```

This would avoid throwing away the key.

Comment: Your (always excellent) answer might be a bit terse for a Swift newbie.